# Issue with operands types in RISC-V: sw with a label, no register

Tags: assembly, memory, riscv

```
.macro read_char
    li a7, 7 # read a character from the standard input
    ecall
    lw t0, char_pos # load the current position
    sb a0, (t0) # store the character at the current position
    addi t0, t0, 1 # increment the current position
    sw t1, char_pos # store the updated position
```

In my sw line, it says that it is too few or incorrect operands. I thought that I was storing the character in the position of char_pos. char_pos is defined as char1.

Answer (score 3):

The forms `lw t1, label` and `sw t1, label` are pseudo instructions that expand to multiple instructions by assemblers of MIPS & RISC V (MARS & RARS).

However, RISC V does not support the form `sw t1, label`.  As compared with MIPS, they did away with the `$at`, aka `$1`, register — a register dedicated as the "assembler temporary".  RISC V does support the form `lw t1, label`, and it does this using the target (here `t1`) as a temporary register before overwriting it with the load result.

However, there is no register being written for `sw`, so there is also no register available to use as scratch temporary in that pseudo instruction.  And because RISC V makes better choices in register usage, they removed the register designated as "assembler temporary".  This, plus several other features (eliminating `$k0` and `$k1`, as well as using more registers in parameter passing) help RISC V behave as if it has 3-5 more registers than MIPS in practice, despite that both have only 31 registers.

What can you do?

Since your macro is known to overwrite `a7`, you can then also use that as follows:

```
la a7, char_pos
sw t1,(a7)
```

This will cost 3 instructions (`la`, also a pseudo instruction, expanding into 2 instructions).

Ideally, though that sequence would take only two instructions, so you would do `lui a7, %hi(char_pos)` followed by `sw t1,%lo(char_pos)(a7)`, taking advantage of the previously unused 12-bit immediate in the `sw` — however RARS doesn't support these `%` functions.

So for starters, I'd just do the above `la`/`sw` sequence.  And also, I would only do one `la` and use it for both as `lw t0, (a7)` and later the `sw t1, (a7)`, eliminating the use of both `lw` and `sw` pseudo instruction forms.

Alternatively, you can use any register besides `a7`, but the more registers a macro uses, the fewer available to the code invoking the macro (and the more for the assembly programmer to be aware of).

---

That macro doesn't really buy much (but if you are supposed to use a macro, well then..).  That macro is specific to storing characters using a particular global variable, so not that general purpose.  The macro combined with the use of the pseudo instructions obscures potential efficiency techniques that would occur, as @Peter says, if the macro is used in the body of a loop, which seems likely due to its nature.

In a small loop, you would load `char_pos` into a register outside of and before the loop and keep it there for the duration of the loop, leaving just the increment inside the loop (store `char_pos` after the loop is fully completed, if needed) — in some use cases, I can imagine the global variable would not even be necessary, a register alone sufficing as the storage for that logical variable.

Comment: Or much better in this case, keep `char_pos` in a register inside this loop, not storing/reloading.  Pointers inside loops are exactly the kind of thing registers are for.